# Toolbar doesnt cast shadow in my app on my device (Android studio)

Tags: java, android, toolbar, shadow, elevation

I have  a toolbar layout and mainlayout .
In my mainlayout I include my toolbar layout :

Toolbar layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/PrimaryButtonsAndHeadscolor"
android:titleTextAppearance="@color/ColorPrimaryDark"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:elevation="8dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

My main layout (the part with the toolbar):

```
  <LinearLayout


    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainScreen"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        >

      >
    <include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    ></include>
    </LinearLayout>
```

On andorid studio at the "preview" screen my tool bar cast a shadow , but when I run it on my device it doesn't.
I know that elevation attribute is suitable for device running on api 21+ , I am using lgg-4 api22 so it should cast shadow beneath the toolbar (I also see shadow beneath the toolbar in other apps ).
What I am doing worng ?

thanks !

Comment: not working :/ , now here is no shadow in the preview also

Comment: Android 5.1 ,what should I have verify?

Comment: You can try setting `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);`

Comment: I just plugged in this layout to a new blank project, and it works just fine, elevation shadow shows. Tested on 6.0.1

Comment: so the problem in my device ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay , so finally I found the problem : my mistake was the fact I put my toolbar  in an internal LinearLayout (and thats somehow Cancelling the elevation effect when running on device).

Previous Layout :

```
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainScreen"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        >
            >
            <include
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                layout="@layout/tool_bar"
                ></include>
    </LinearLayout>
```

New layout :

```
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainScreen"
    android:orientation="vertical">

            >
            <include
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                layout="@layout/tool_bar"
                ></include>
```

It works,there is a shadow on my toolbar !